# Stop a running VBA compiler from C# without closing the workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C#-application and some library code (which I cannot change) launches an Excel-Workbook with macros in it. If there is an error, I would like to cancel the running VBA macro. I tried to do this by killing Excel, but the C# task then starts to throw exceptions because the workbook is no longer present in its `OnDispose` method. I would therefore like to know whether it is possible to stop the running VBA macro without closing the entire workbook.

```
if (TryGetOpenExcel(out Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp))
{
    try
    {
        var vbaProject = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject;
        // TODO stop the VBA macro or interpreter
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: You might want to lose the VBA tag - it's not really relevant to your question

Comment: @CHill60 removed

Comment: *"...which is triggered from a decompiled code in C#."* I have experience with VBA, C# and VBA-C# interop, but I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: @Heinzi I just wanted to say that I can't change the called code, I just fire a function that starts the excel and triggers the run VBA. when there is an error I want to cancel the operation somehow, one option is to kill the excel process which is a little bit ugly. I thought maybe to stop the vba run somehow

Comment: Hey :) I edited your question such that reading it does not cause headaches anymore. Please check that I edited it correctly and feel free to edit it again if I got something wrong. Cheers :)

Comment: @MarounSassine: *"...when there is an error..."* How do you know that an error has occurred?

Comment: @Heinzi i'm subscribed to the logger window... I read the incomming logs from vbt.

Comment: @MarounSassine: Can you modify the macro?

Comment: @Heinzi I tried to call 'End' in the VBA onError. It pops up a UI debug window which keeps the C# code stuck on the UI thread.  maybe i'm missing a configuration there...

Comment: @MarounSassine: I see. So the problem is that the VBA code currently resumes in case of an error, and you want it to stop, right? In that case, `End` *should* be the right thing to do. If you can reproduce the VBA issue with a [mcve], it might be worth asking a separate question about that.

Comment: I understand, it would be nice also to be able to stop the compiler from C#

Comment: @MarounSassine: What does the compiler have to do with it? I though we are talking about stopping a running macro, not about stopping the compiler. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @Heinzi the original question was about stopping the compiler, missed the question title edit... however stopping the compiler will stop eventually the running macro

Comment: @MarounSassine: *"however stopping the compiler will stop eventually the running macro"* You might have a fundamental misunderstanding here: The compiler is what runs when you choose `Debug/Compile...` from the menu, or what runs automatically (very briefly) if you run a macro that has not been compiled yet. Once the macro runs, the compiler is not involved.

Comment: You want to just leak an excel instance because your disposal code doesn't handle the case where it'd already closed?  That makes no sense.  Just update your disposal code so that it handles the case where the application is ended, if you logically want to end the application.

Comment: @Dai this is what I eventually did.

Comment: @Servy i wish i could change that code... it is not my code, i'll just close Excel and handle exceptions